# debugging Flex ActionScript singleton

Tags: apache-flex, singleton, debugging

When I am stepping through code in the Flex debugger, and enter my singleton class, "this" appears in the variables window but this cannot be expanded. How do you inspect the variables of "this".

Answer (score 0):

right clicking and adding a watch will let you see some of it

Answer (score 0):

Debugger doesn't differentiate between singleton or normal ones. Click on the triangle shaped button towards the left of `this`.